# wagtail - How to get all pages in footer with slug

Tags: python, django, wagtail

HI Tried with template tag

```
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_all_pages(context):
context['all_page'] = Page.objects.live()
return context
```

and in my template

```
{% get_all_pages as queries %}
        {% for each in queries %}
        {{each.page_title}}
        {% endfor %}
```

All pages are not passed in my templates , i want to add all pages in footer please help

Comment: Try to return from get_all_pages function queryset itself, not context dict: `return Page.objects.all()`

Comment: hey thanks din't worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two problems here:

- As neverwalkaloner says, a `simple_tag` should return the value you want to output or assign, rather than updating the context dict:

  ```
  @register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
  def get_all_pages(context):
      return Page.objects.live()
  ```
- `page_title` is not a recognised property of a page object - it should be `title`:

  ```
  {{ each.title }}
  ```